# How to make bold all of the TOC by default?

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to make all the table of contents bold by default?

Comment: Is there any compelling reason why you want to do this?

Comment: Because, the institute to which my PhD dissertation should have to be submitted has such outrageously weird thesis writing rules.

Comment: I understand and sympathize with you.

Comment: If your graduate school is full of prehistoric creatures that force you to put a TOC, LOF and LOT with full bold faces to your document read this carefully. First of all you have to use `tocloft` package. For the TOC Heiko already gave the answer. For LOF and LOT add his answer the following:
    `\g@addto@macro\cftfigfont{\bfseries} 
    \g@addto@macro\cfttabfont{\bfseries}
    \g@addto@macro\cftfigpagefont{\bfseries}
    \g@addto@macro\cfttabpagefont{\bfseries}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Standard classes

The standard classes `article`, `report`, `book` do not provide an interface to change the font of the entries in the table of contents.

The following example for class `article` patches the macros that generate the table of contents to add the missing `\bfseries`.

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\@dottedtocline` is used for the entries of `\section` (class `report` and `book`),
  and `\subsection` to `\subparagraph` (classes `article`, `report` and `book`).
- The standard classes use `\normalfont` for the page number in `\@dottedtocline`. Thus the [nice trick of karlkoller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122589/16967) `\textbf{\tableofcontents` will fail for some of the page numbers.

**Math**

Also math elements in the titles can be made bold in the table of contents, see
the [comment of blackburn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122588/how-to-make-bold-all-of-the-toc-by-default#comment274255_122589). Remarks:

- In general, however, this is not a good idea, because some mathematicians use bold to make a vector or tensor. Thus adding bold can change the meaning of the math expressions.
- On the other hand, mixing different font series in the title does look to good either.
- And too much math in the titles should be avoided anyway.

Nevertheless here an extended example that sets `\boldmath` for the document division titles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{\leavevmode}{\leavevmode\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@part}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
% \patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}% report/book
\patchcmd{\l@section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}% article

\patchcmd{\@part}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@spart}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
% \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}% report/book
% \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}% % report/book
\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\paragraph}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subparagraph}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Einstein: $E=mc^2$}
\section{Hello world $\alpha+1=\infty$}
\subsection{Foo bar $\beta*3=\emptyset$}
\subsubsection{Sub sub}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Class `memoir`

Other classes or packages (e.g. `titletoc`) can provide a more elaborate interface for formatting the table of contents.

Example with class `memoir` (without `\boldmath` for simplicity):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\addtodef*{\cftsectionfont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cftsubsectionfont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cftparagraphfont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cftsubparagraphfont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cftfigurefont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cfttablefont}{}{\bfseries}

\addtodef*{\cftsectionpagefont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cftparagraphpagefont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cftsubparagraphpagefont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cftfigurepagefont}{}{\bfseries}
\addtodef*{\cfttablepagefont}{}{\bfseries}

\renewcommand*{\cftdot}{\bfseries.}

\settocdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part title}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Hello world}
\subsection{Foo bar}
\subsubsection{Sub sub}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result memoir]

### Package `tocloft`

Package `tocloft` provides similar commands as class `memoir` (both are written by the same author, Peter Wilson). The missing `\addtodef` is replaced by LaTeX's `\g@addto@macro` and the document division names are shorter (e.g. `sec` instead of `section`):

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\cftsecfont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cftsubsecfont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cftparafont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cftsubparafont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cftfigfont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cfttabfont{\bfseries}

\g@addto@macro\cftsecpagefont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cftsubsecpagefont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cftparapagefont{\bfseries} 
\g@addto@macro\cftsubparapagefont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cftfigpagefont{\bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\cfttabpagefont{\bfseries}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I was waiting for a nice answer from you, thanks. Anyway, I have a doubt: is there anything that one can do in this case? `\section{The \texttt{\#include} directive}`

Comment: @karlkoeller: Using a typewriter font family that provides a bold variant helps. Instead of the Computer Modern fonts, the Latin modern fonts (`\usepackage{lmodern}`) can be used, for example.

Comment: Thanks very much, Heiko. This is just what I wanted to know.

Comment: Sorry but it did not work for me. I guess it is because of fancyhdr package which i have to use for page numbering: `\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{fancy}`

Comment: @oakenshield1: Please edit your question to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also add a more descriptive problem description. "Does not work" can be anything from a serious error message to a forgotten element that is not bold.

Comment: @oakenshield1: Unless the table of contents is very short, `\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{fancy}` will rather change the page style for the last page.

Comment: I'm adding a [minimal working example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39371917/MWE.tar.gz). `main.tex` file is the original file as you might guess.

Comment: @heiko-oberdiek I've added a MWE. I'll be grateful if you have a look at it.

Comment: @oakenshield1: I have updated the answer for package `tocloft`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Worked like a charm. Now is it possible to do the same thing to LOF and LOT.

Comment: @oakenshield1: Answer updated.

Answer (score 6):

A very simple manner in a nonconventional way?

```
\textbf{\tableofcontents}
```

Comment: Also add `\boldmath` for making math bold.

Comment: @blackburn right, but it is really a nonconventional way... I bet this answer will have no upvotes...

Comment: I strongly feel, this is one of the many possible answer. I am giving an upvote, since this answer surely helps a beginner.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't use boldface for the page numbers.

Comment: @blackburn Thanks, but in this way you made me lose the bet... `:-)`

Comment: I've tried this before but it did not work for me. Most probably because of the reason (i.e. fancy headers) I've mentioned in the comments of the answer above.

Comment: @oakenshield1 no, `\thispagestyle{fancy}` is not the cause. Add an MWE to your question as suggested by Heiko.

Comment: @karlkoeller please find the MWE and have a look at [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39371917/MWE.tar.gz).