# Change Section titles to Small Caps only in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, small-caps

I'm new to LaTeX and already facing my first problem. I want to change all section titles to small caps in the table of contents but **not** in the text.

I'm using WriteLaTeX and `article` as document class.

This is how my document is structured

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Section 1.1}
\subsection{Section 1.2}

\newpage
\section{Section 2}

\newpage
\section{Section 3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See [How to make bold all of the TOC by default?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122588/27635). It might help.

Comment: You mean section titles only or subsections too?

Comment: Only section titles

Comment: The `tocloft` package will solve your problems, see my answer. But this question could be generalized to something like "How do I change the style of a part of the table of contents?" Answer: The tocloft manual (pp 8-12) provides an overview of all relevant commands. You're likely to find something there. `\ctfsecfont`, in this case, but tocloft provides commands for parts, chapters, subsections, paragraphs, figures etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Optimal Solution**

Load the `tocloft` package and put `\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\scshape}` after it in the preamble. MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\scshape}
\begin{document}

\title{My document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{first section}
bla

\subsection{a subsection}
bla

\section{second section}
bla
\end{document}
```

This will only change the TOC, not your headings.

**Subpar solution**

If, for any reason, you cannot load tocloft, this is the ugliest hack ever:

```
% make your sections using \newsection{title}

\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{
\stepcounter{section}
\section*{\arabic{section}. #1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\scshape \arabic{section}. #1}
}
```

Comment: Note that `\sc` has been deprecated since 1994; prefer `\scshape` instead.

Comment: Also the `\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\scshape}` should be in the preamble.

Comment: Noted and edited!

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison, here's a solution using the [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc) package, the important part is

```
\titlecontents{section}
[0pt]                                               % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                               % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    \large\scshape}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]                                                  % below code (e.g vertical space)
```

I loaded the [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) package just for demonstration.

Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titlecontents{section}
[0pt]                                               % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                               % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    \large\scshape}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]                                                  % below code (e.g vertical space)


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\loop
\section{Section text}
\ifnum\value{section}<5\repeat

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will change all the section heading to small-cap font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \scshape #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Section 1.1}
\subsection{Section 1.2}

\newpage
\section{Section 2}

\newpage
\section{Section 3}
\end{document}
```

The command `l@section` is redefined to change all section to small-cap. Package [`fontenc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) is used to make bold small-cap to appear in the ToC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need just the section titles not the subsection titles to be in small caps

Comment: Ok. Now I updated the code with `\l@section` redefined for the specific requirement.