# Remove font styles in list of figures

Tags: fonts, subcaption

together with `latex` i use the `subcaption` package for subfigures. I use different font styles (like italics, bold, sans serif) in the captions for certain terms. Those font styles are used in the list of figures as well.

Now my question is, if there is any way to overwrite all font styles for the list of figures automatically (without using `\caption[without style]{with style}`). In the list of figures only one font shall be used.

And i have another question: How can i reduce the spacing between the number (a,b,...) and the title of the subfigure in the list of figures?

Comment: This thread deals with the TOC, but you may have some hints: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122588/27635

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility: the idea is to `\let` the font attributes you don't want to use in the list to be, for example `\rmfamily` (for font switches) or `\textrm` (for font commands with one argument); this is done `\AtBeginDocument` using `\addtocontents{lof}{...}` so the redefinitions only have effect for the LoF.

To change the separation between the number/letter and the title for subfigures in the LoF, you need to redefine `\l@subsubsection` (for `article`) or `\l@subsection` (for `book`, `report`); this redefinition has to be done *before* loading `subcaption`; then, you can redefine it again, to restore its original meaning for the ToC, if you want to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{2em}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=true}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    \let\sffamily\rmfamily
    \let\scshape\rmfamily
    \let\textbf\textrm
    \let\textit\textrm
  }
}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
A
\caption{{\scshape test} \textbf{subfigure}}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
B
\caption{another {\sffamily test} \textit{subfigure}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can define a conditional command that applies or not the formatting given as its argument; the conditional is set to false at the start of the list of figure and to true at its end.

Formatting commands not prefixed by `\maybe` will be honored anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=true}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\formatfalse}}
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\formattrue}}
\newif\ifformat
\formattrue
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\maybe}[1]{%
  \ifformat
    \expandafter#1%
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
A
\caption{\maybe\textsc{test} \maybe\textbf{subfigure}}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
B
\caption{another \maybe\textsf{test} \maybe\textit{subfigure}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to Gonzalo for the example document.

Comment: With this solution i would have to modify each caption individually. This is what i wanted to prevent.